# Cant login with docker compose to Postgres via pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/pgdata
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"

  pdadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
     PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: example@gmail.com 
     PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: example

volumes:
  postgres:
```

when I try to login to postgres via pgadmin i am getting the error: `password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

I am trying with user `postgres` and password `postgres`.
I also tryied to add explisit `POSTGRES_USER` to the env with no success.

How can I login to my postgres database?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're very close:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres # <-- add this
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/pgdata
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  pdadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: example@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: example
    depends_on: # <-- add this
      - db # <-- add this
    links: # <-- add this
      - db # <-- add this

volumes:
  postgres:
```

Then connect to pgadmin http://localhost:8080
when you want to add new server you need to add the IP of the container

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container_id>
```

That it !

Comment: Thank you, but I get the same error. I don't think its a network issue. in both cases the error is coming from the database and not from the pgadmin, I see it in the db logs

Comment: That weird, got it working for me with this exact compose file

Comment: Try to flush everything you can, Think before doing following

`docker volume prune`
`docker network prune`

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: Example123
```

Use a mixture of upper and lower case letters and numerics

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).